# Opencart admin login redirects to cart

Tags: opencart

I have a fresh install of opencart 1.5.5.1

When I access the admin, I get the login page, I login and get redirected to `/admin/index.php?route=common/login` which displays the homepage of the cart and not the admin panel.

How can I access the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you try to log in and have a redirect in place to go from the non-www version to the www version of your domain (or vice-versa). If you have this, you will need to adjust your `/admin/config.php` to use the correct domain (ie so no redirect is necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Check your admin htacess file!
In my case  this was the problem.
So navigate here:
/admin
And search this file:
**.htacess.txt**
Remove txt and you be fine!